# Use of uninitialized value $guess in numeric lt (<) line 25 in Perl

Tags: perl, random

I'm very new to Perl and have been given an assignment that is a simple guessing game where the user is given 8 chances to guess a number between 1 and 100. I keep getting the error mentioned above and cannot figure it out.

Here's my code:

```
    use Modern::Perl;

    my ($guess,$target,$counter); 
    $target = (int rand 100) + 1;

    while ($guess < $target)
    {
        chomp ($guess=<>);
        print "Enter guess $counter: ";

        $counter++;

        if ($guess eq $target) {
            print "\nCongratulations! You guessed the secret number $target in   $counter";
        }
        elsif ($guess > $target) {
            print "\nYour guess, $guess, is too high.";
        }
        elsif ($guess < $target) {
            print "\nYour guess, $guess, is too low.";
        }
        else {
            print "You lose. The number was $target.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since there are only 25 lines of code in the script you show us, how are we to guess which line your `$guess` is not initialized on?  Please, ensure that your code snippet and error message are self-consistent. I'd guess that it is the `while` line, which probably has the wrong condition on it (probably should have `!=` instead of `<`). And you can fix it by providing an initial guess that's invalid; `$guess = -1;` for example. You might want to think about when the `$counter` is used, and when you should test for more than the limit of guesses. You might intend your `else` clause for that.

Comment: If you're doing comparing two values as numbers, use `==` as the operator, not `eq`.  `eq` is for comparing strings for equality, and `lt` and `gt` are for string comparisons of less than and greater than.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code suffers a few issues. Here is my code, using a different approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.012;   # use strict; use feature 'say';
use warnings;

my $number = (int rand 100) + 1;
my $max_guesses = 8;

GUESS: foreach my $guess_no (1..$max_guesses) {
  say "($guess_no) Please enter a guess:";
  my $guess = <>;
  chomp $guess;

  unless ($guess =~ /^\d+$/) {
    say "Hey, that didn't look like a number!";
    redo GUESS;
  }

  if ($guess == $number) {
    say "Congrats, you were on target!";
    last GUESS;
  } elsif ($guess < $number) {
    say "Nay, your guess was TOO SMALL.";
  } elsif ($guess > $number) {
    say "Nay, your guess was TOO BIG.";
  } else {
    die "Illegal state";
  }

  if ($guess_no == $max_guesses) {
    say "However, you have wasted all your guesses. YOU LOOSE.";
    last GUESS;
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
$ perl guess-the-number.pl
(1) Please enter a guess:
15
Nay, your guess was TOO SMALL.
(2) Please enter a guess:
60
Nay, your guess was TOO BIG.
(3) Please enter a guess:
45
Nay, your guess was TOO BIG.
(4) Please enter a guess:
30
Nay, your guess was TOO SMALL.
(5) Please enter a guess:
38
Congrats, you were on target!
```

(all other corner cases (too many guesses, non-numbers as input) work as expected)

What did I do differently?

- I didn't loop while the guess was too small (← bug!). Instead, I did a loop iteration for each guess. However, a `while (1)` loop would have worked as well.
- I did a sanity check on the input, using a simple regular expression. It asserts that the input will be considered numeric by Perl. Else, you get to redo the guess.
- I initialize all variables as soon as I declare them. This removes any possibilities of uninitialized values popping up in error messages.
- I use proper comparision operators. Perl scalars come in two flavours: stringy and numeric:

  ```
  Stringy  Numeric
  lt       <
  le       <=
  eq       ==
  ne       !=
  ge       >=
  gt       >
  cmp      <=>
  ```
- The `say` function prints the string like `print`, but appends a newline. This removes akward `\n`s at the beginning or the end of the string. It makes reading code easier.

Comment: Would `$guess =~ /^\d+$/` work better to trap non-number input, for this case?

Comment: @Kenosis You are right — my previous check assumed no warnings. Fixed it. But now we can't input our guesses in exponential: `5E1` et cetera :(

Comment: You're right.  Perhaps too much for this program, but could `use Scalar::Util::Numeric qw/isnum/;` and `unless (isnum $guess) { ...`, as it handled your `5E1` well.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention which line was line #25! That could be important.

However, look at your `while` statement. Notice you're comparing `$guess` with `$target`, but you haven't set `$guess` yet. That's set ***inside*** you're `while` loop. This is why you're getting the undefined variable.

I also don't see where `$counter` is set. That could also be an issue.

Let's look at your `while` loop a bit closer:

```
while ( $guess < $target ) {
    blah, blah, blah
}
```

Assuming that there's a `$guess`, you're looping until the user guesses a number bigger than the `$target`. Is that what you want? No, you stated that you wanted to give the user eight turns, and that's it. What you want is something more along the lines of:

```
 my $count = 1;
 while ( $count <= 8 ) {
     $count++;
     blah, blah, blah
 }
```

A slightly nicer way of doing this is with a for loop:

```
for ( my $count = 1; $count <= 8; $count++ ) {
    blah, blah, blah
}
```

However, these C-style for loops are so passé. Plus, there's a clearer way of doing this using the `1..8` syntax. This is the same as saying `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)`. It's clean and easy to understand:

```
 for my $counter (1..8) {
     blah, blah, blah
 }
```

(**NOTE**: Some people use a `foreach` keyword instead of a `for` keyword when doing this type of loop to distinguish it from the C-Style for loop. However, some people (cough! Damian Conway, cough!) frown upon the use of `foreach` since it doesn't really add clarity.)

Let's look at another aspect of your logic:

```
if ($guess eq $target) {
    print "\nCongratulations! You guessed the secret number $target in   $counter";
}
elsif ($guess > $target) {
    print "\nYour guess, $guess, is too high.";
}
elsif ($guess < $target) {
    print "\nYour guess, $guess, is too low.";
}
else {  #Do this if the guess isn't equal to, greater than or less than the target
    print "You lose. The number was $target.";
}
```

When will your `else` clause be executed? Answer is never. After all, you won't exeucte it unless `$guess` is neither greater than, equal to, or less than `$target`. Also, even if you did *lose*, you're still in that loop.

What you probably want to do is to put the *You lose* line outside the loop. That way, after the eighth guess and your loop ends, you get the *You lose* spiel.

Also, let's look at this line:

```
chomp ( $guess = <> );
print "Enter guess $counter: ";
```

First, the `<>` is the *null filehandle operator* which is very, very different from `<STDIN>`:

> The null filehandle <> is special: it can be used to emulate the behavior of sed and awk, and any other Unix filter program that takes a list of filenames, doing the same to each line of input from all of them. Input from <> comes either from standard input, or from each file listed on the command line. Here's how it works: the first time <> is evaluated, the @ARGV array is checked, and if it is empty, $ARGV[0] is set to "-", which when opened gives you standard input. The @ARGV array is then processed as a list of filenames.

What you want is `<STDIN>`.

Also notice that you are getting the input before you print out your prompt. You really want to do this instead:

```
print "Enter guess $counter: ";
chomp ($guess = <STDIN>);
```

Also, you want to set `$|` to a nonzero value to turn off buffering. Otherwise, you might still have to enter your `$guess` before you see the prompt.

Here's the revised program `Modern::Perl` doesn't work on my system, so I use the three separate pragmas to cover it:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use constant {
    UPPER_RANGE => 100,
    MAX_GUESSES => 8,
};

$| = 1;
my $target = int ( ( rand UPPER_RANGE ) + 1 );

for my $counter (1..MAX_GUESSES) {
    print "Enter guess #$counter: ";
    chomp ( my $guess = <STDIN> );

    if ($guess == $target) {
        say "Congratulations! You guessed the secret number $target in $counter turns";
        exit;
    }   
    elsif ($guess > $target) {
        say "Your guess, $guess, is too high.";
    }   
    else {
        say "Your guess, $guess, is too low.";
    }   
}   
say "You lose. The number was $target.";
```

A few things I didn't cover:

- When doing numeric comparisons, use the `==` operator and not `eq` which is for strings.
- I use `say` instead of `print` when I can. The `say` command is like `print` except it automatically puts a NL on the end for me.
- Notice the `exit;` after I stated you won. I want to end my program at that point.
- Notice I don't declare all of my variables until I need them. In my program, `$guess` and `$counter` only exists inside the `for` loop while `$target` exists both inside and outside the `for` loop.
- I `use constant` to help avoid *mysterious* numbers. For example, `1..MAX_GUESSES` helps me understand that the loop is going to my maximum guess while `1..8` doesn't explain why I'm going to 8. Also, I can simply change my constant and suddenly you have 10 changes of guessing a number between 1 and 1000.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you aren't explicitly initializing your variables. By default, Perl initializes the variables you create with `my()` to the `undef` value. So take a look at the following line in your script:

```
my ($guess,$target,$counter);
```

This line creates three variables, **all of which** are set to `undef`. For more details on the ins and outs of the `my()` operator, check out the [perlsub docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Private-Variables-via-my%28%29). Here's a relevant quote from that doc page:

> The parameter list to my() may be assigned to if desired, which allows
>   you to initialize your variables. (If no initializer is given for a
>   particular variable, it is created with the undefined value.)